# SQL CE unspecified error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, sql-server-ce

I did a project with MS SQL Server CE that when installed in the 'costumer' machine just raises an unspecified excpetion.

Did some research and looks like I did everything mentioned. The dev env has sql compact 3.5 installed and sql tools for vs 2005. Using dotNet 3.5. But to make it run in de dev machine I need to add the sqlcese30, sqlceqp30, sqlceme and sqlcecompact30 dlls and its works fine.

The setup project put dotNet 2.0 as dependecy and I also added the dlls but it raises the exception and I cannot see where or what it is. Its just a single 'unspecified error' message.

please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [SQL CE re-distributable installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dc614aee-7e1c-4881-9c32-3a6ce53384d9&displaylang=en) on the customer machine?

You can add SQL CE 3.5 as a pre-requisite to the setup project. If it is not already in the list, copy the `SQL Server Compact Edition` directory from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages` to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\BootStrapper\Packages` and restart Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: Yes I did. I have the redistributable but didnt find the Bootstrapper you mentioned. Theres just the bootstrapper for 3.1 what makes me think that at the end the application just uses 3.1.

Comment: ALmost there. I downloaded and installed the 3.1 redistributable in the costumer machine and the error gone. In fact i'm just filling a datagridview for now, but looks good.

Shouldnt be better if I could use dotNet 3.5 and SQL CE 3.5 SP1 as dependencies instead? And how do I do to the setup project add it automatically to my output?

Comment: Other thing I note is that theres no SDK download on the CE page for 3.5 SP1.

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact-downloads.aspx#31